# Is it possible to serialize / deserialize protobuf binaries to text editable schemes alike json?

Tags: protocol-buffers

I've got struct definition in proto files.

And I want to have data definition somewhere too, in xml or json or alike...

So next I will put (compile) it to bin and use as binary.

Is there good way to serialize Text json-alike files into protobuf bin following proto struct definition?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There *is* actually a text-based protocol included in protobuf; the API for this is [described here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/reference/cpp/google.protobuf.text_format), with an example [from here](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/overview) of:

```
person {
  name: "John Doe"
  email: "jdoe@example.com"
}
```

However, this is **not** the actual [protobuf encoding](https://developers.google.com/protocol-buffers/docs/encoding), and you should note that not all implementations provide support for this format. Personally, I would handle any "serialize as xml/json/etc" as a separate requirement, and employ a different tool (a dedicated, best-of-breed, xml/json/etc serializer).